# Strange error when compiling with vc++ 2012

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I got a strange problem. I got the some errors when compiling in visual studio 2012 c++ the following:

```
#include "crew_sched.h"

    int var_tab = 7;

    for ( int = 0; i < var_tab; i++) {
        cout << i ;
    }
```

The loop isn't being recognized, as you can see:

```
1>------ Operación Compilar iniciada: proyecto: cs_main_windows, configuración: Debug Win32 ------
1>  modelo_clasico.cpp
1>d:\visual studio c++\proj_windutygen\proj_windutygen\modelo_clasico.h(5): error C2059: error de sintaxis : 'for'

1>d:\visual studio c++\proj_windutygen\proj_windutygen\modelo_clasico.h(5): error C2143: error de sintaxis : falta ')' delante de ';'

1>d:\visual studio c++\proj_windutygen\proj_windutygen\modelo_clasico.h(5): error C2143: error de sintaxis : falta ';' delante de '<'

1>d:\visual studio c++\proj_windutygen\proj_windutygen\modelo_clasico.h(5): error C4430: falta el especificador de tipo; se presupone int. Nota: C++ no admite default-int

1>d:\visual studio c++\proj_windutygen\proj_windutygen\modelo_clasico.h(5): error C2143: error de sintaxis : falta ';' delante de '++'

1>d:\visual studio c++\proj_windutygen\proj_windutygen\modelo_clasico.h(5): error C2086: 'int i' : nueva definición

1>          d:\visual studio c++\proj_windutygen\proj_windutygen\modelo_clasico.h(5) : vea la declaración de 'i'

1>d:\visual studio c++\proj_windutygen\proj_windutygen\modelo_clasico.h(5): error C2059: error de sintaxis : ')'

1>d:\visual studio c++\proj_windutygen\proj_windutygen\modelo_clasico.h(5): error C2143: error de sintaxis : falta ';' delante de '{'

1>d:\visual studio c++\proj_windutygen\proj_windutygen\modelo_clasico.h(5): error C2447: '{' : falta el encabezado de función (¿lista formal de estilo anterior?)

========== Compilar: 0 correctos, 1 incorrectos, 0 actualizados, 0 omitidos ==========
```

SOLVED: I see the problem thanks to the comments made. I need to make a function. Very newbie error. I need to sleep :)
Thanks!

Comment: For those who don't speak Spanish, C4430 is "missing type specifier - int assumed". Can you please post a bigger fragment? Is your `var_tab` outside of a function or class? (i.e. is it a global variable?)

Answer (score 3):

Assignments, loops, ... outside of functions are not allowed. Initializations, on the other hand, are, so

```
int var_tab = 7;
```

would be fine outside a function, but your actual code has to be in a function. Start with an `int main() { ...your code here...}` and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

In for loop `int = 0` should be `int i = 0`